# How to get access to twitter ads api?

Tags: forms, api, twitter, client, ads-api

after a lot of back and forth with the Twitter documentation I am now able to authenticate with OAuth 1.0 and make request behalf on the user who sign-ined and accepted my app to preform changes / retrieve data. 
Now, I'm trying to make requests to the Twitter Ads API.
This is the error I get:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED_CLIENT_APPLICATION","message":"The client application making this request does not have access to this API"}],"request":{"params":{}}}
```

As it seems, there is a need of another app registration. [I registered it](https://dev.twitter.com/form/ads-api-access-developer) with my app id, assuming the 'developer' stage is the fit for me. I'm trying to retrieve analytics, e.g., [retrieve campaigns](https://dev.twitter.com/ads/reference/get/stats/accounts/%3Aaccount_id) for the user who accepted it.

After registration the Ads App Form, the error stays the same. The docs don't specify if there is a need for a special implementation for the ads-api. Also, the Ads App I opened isn't mentioned anywhere, nor in my [twitter apps](https://apps.twitter.com/).

Am I missing something? 
Thanks before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at [Twitter ads API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/ads/overview), getting access is a pretty involved process. From their site, you'll need:

- One positive referral from a client, advertiser or Twitter team
  (outside of Ads API)
- Clear value proposition on how how your solution
  will supplement the Twitter ads offering and improve advertiser
  performance
- History of compliance with Twitter developer policies
- Experience running Twitter Ads
- Twitter App ID associated with a corporate @username, with no more than 5 active tokens

It seems a little overkill, but I haven't seen any other way around it. If you find a better way to get ads API access, please post another answer here because I have a potential project that would use these APIs, but the application process has been too daunting to really justify starting the effort.

Comment: It's changed a bit since you answered, but it's not any easier.  They now want two testimonials from clients with a minimum spend, plus a working demo of a "functional, attractive design". So I agree, it's far too much difficult to justify the effort and there's no guarantee they won't move the goalposts on you in future. There *is* now an entry-level developer tier, so you can build an app *first* without doing all that. (Note I'm a little biased in that I regard social media in general, and Twitter in particular, with contempt.)

Answer (score 2):

As of Sept 2016, the application process appears to be much easier.

[image]

It appears you no longer need positive referrals, value props, history, or experience running Twitter ads.

Comment: Unfortunately all they've done is hidden all that and shifted it to the next stage - completing the form will give you (after a week or so) "developer" level access, to upgrade to "standard" you need a demo of a "functional, attractive design", *two* referrals from clients with a minimum spend ($500 or $5k depending on size).